# Quickly locate the product configuration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When starting working on an unfamiliar Java project, how do I quickly locate the **product configuration**? The normal way I know is first you have to know which project the product configuration is located, then expand that project in the package explorer and double click the "`.product`" file. What if I don't have this information? Do I have to search the "`.product`" in the file system to find out its path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your project has a `.product` file (maybe you meant a `.project` file), you could use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and then enter ".product" (or ".project") in the **Open Resource** pop-up.